# Scrollview with Linear and Relative Layout is all boxed up, so I cannot reposition items

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, scrollview

I am creating a ScrollView to house my relativelayout. The RelativeLayout seems to need to be inside a LinearLayout (from online). However it has gone all boxed up, with the items overlapping each other. This means I cannot reposition stuff. How can I fix this? My code is like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
tools:context=".AddParty" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addparty_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:onClick="switch_peoplechoice"
        android:text="@string/addparty_switch" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addparty_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addparty_switch"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addparty_switch"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:onClick="cancel"
        android:text="@string/addparty_cancel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addparty_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addparty_title"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addparty_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addparty_venue"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/addparty_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addparty_venue"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/addparty_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addparty_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addparty_time"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And like all properly filled out. I actually just inserted the LinearLayout and ScrollView around my relativelayout I already had. Is there a better solution to needing a RelativeLayout to scroll, or what am I doing wrong. 
It get's all bunched up in the UI viewer in Eclipse...
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you copy all of your layout xml ?

Comment: I don't think you need `LinearLayout` to wrap `RelativeLayout`. Have you tried removing `LinearLayout` and use `RelativeLayout` as the only child of `ScrollView`?

Comment: I'm just updating it. I think I may be able to use just a RelativeLayout. I can't think why I shouldn't, but online the examples have wrapped the RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout.

Comment: I do actually, in my actual code, close the ScrollView as well... Just in case.

Comment: @SwedishArchitect it is just that is a much more easy way for demo and examples, it is not just only layout compatible with ScrollView, below is code from developer.android.com - "A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager . A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through."

See here-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: @Akhil Jain, I don't use a LinearLayout anymore. I used a RelativeLayout, but I still get the problem. Thanks though

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say "it has gone all boxed up" ? Your Views are not the way you want them to be ? Can you show an example of how it should correctly look and how it look now ?

Comment: They all go inside of this box which has limited space, and overlap each other.

Comment: @SwedishArchitect your problem is not the relative layout, but how you draw those elements on screen and also try to set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for your `relative layout` add some fixed `dp` for `android:layout_width="300dp"` height should not be provided as such but for testing its ok

Answer (score 1):

Your items are overlapping one another in the RelativeLayout as you most likely did not specifiy the positions of each item individualy, though it is difficult to determine without seeing the entire layout xml.

Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html for more information on how RelativeLayouts work.

Comment: Ok, I specify them relative to each other. Are you saying I need to specify their locations using "19dp" etc.?

Comment: @SwedishArchitect Relative layout is based more on sibling position, see example here -http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Comment: OK, in my code I have, I think, made them relative to each, so they don't overlap. To clarify, I made a relativeLayout, and added the scrollview around it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the XML is concerned, it seems that their is a conception mistake on how your Views are related to each others.

Let's start with the RelativeLayout that has a `wrap_content` height. No problem on that but it must be noted.

The first element inside this RelativeLayout is positioned at the bottom of the RelativeLayout. Still no problem on this point.

Thing is, the second View is positioned ABOVE the first one, this means that the height of the RelativeLayout is getting bigger when the second View is inserted, but the first View should be at the bottom of the layout so it is repositioned again thus overlap with the second View.

Can you try to position the first View with `layout_alignParentTop="true"` ? 
Maybe this will fixe your problem.